# Integer Validation Python

Tags: python, validation, while-loop, integer

I need to add a validation whilst in a while loop.

However when I use this validation it doesn't work and instead only comes up with the error message saying I haven't used a base 10/an integer when I want it to come up with the validation error message and let the user try again.

I don't know if having it in a while loop makes the validation I use any different, does it?

Also do I need to change this "def inputNumber(message):" to what my input is stored as?

And this "userInput = int(input(message))" to what my input is stored as?

```
import time 
import random 
question = 0 
score = 0 
name = input("What is your full name?") 
print ("Hello " + name, "welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz. Use integers to enter the answer!") 
time.sleep(2) 
operands1 = list(range(2, 12)) 
operators = ["+","-","x"] 
operands2 = list(range(2, 12)) 

while question < 10:  
    operand1 = random.choice(operands1)
    operand2 = random.choice(operands2) 
    operator = random.choice(operators) 
    def inputNumber(message):
        while True:
            try:
               userInput = int(input(message))       
            except ValueError:
                print("Not an integer! Try again.")
                continue
            else:
                return userInput 
            break
    user_answer =int(input('{} {} {} = '.format(operand1, operator, operand2)))
```

Comment: In the last line, I think you wanted to do `user_answer =int(inputNumber('{} {} {} = '.format(operand1, operator, operand2)))` but instead did `user_answer =int(input('{} {} {} = '.format(operand1, operator, operand2)))`?

Comment: `def inputNumber(message)` defines a function named `inputNumber` on every iteration of the loop. You're not actually calling it.

Comment: @muhammadtahir I have now changed this and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want to have your function definitions within a while loop like you're doing here:

```
while question < 10:
    ... 
    def inputNumber(message): 
        ...
```

Instead, you can define the function *outside* the loop and call it x number of times from a loop elsewhere. E.g.

```
def inputNumber(message): 
    ...
    return userInput

while question < 10:
    # pick random numbers/operators
    ...
    # call inputNumber() with numbers/operators as message. Return user_answer
    user_answer = int(inputNumber('{} {} {} = '.format(operand1, operator, operand2)))
    # check if the answer is correct
    ...
    # increment question so it doesn't run infinitely
    question += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@user6104134 has already solved this problem; however, I'd like to provide an answer for anyone else having similar issues.

## Try this solution

```
import random
import time

question = 0
score = 0


def inputnumber(prompt):
    while True:
        response = raw_input(prompt)
        try:
            if isinstance(response, int):
                return int(response)
            else:
                print "Not an integer! Try again."
        except ValueError:
            print "Not an integer! Try again."


name = raw_input("What is your full name? ")
print ("Hello " + name, "welcome to The Arithmetic Quiz. Use integers to enter the answer!")
time.sleep(2)
operands1 = list(range(2, 12))
operators = ["+", "-", "x"]
operands2 = list(range(2, 12))

while question < 10:
    operand1 = random.choice(operands1)
    operand2 = random.choice(operands2)
    operator = random.choice(operators)
    user_answer = int(inputnumber('{} {} {} = '.format(operand1, operator, operand2)))
    question += 1
```

### Issues

First, you should declare function definitions outside of your script and call the function by identifier 'inputNumber()'

Also notice the slight change in Try/Except, and the [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant formatting.